# I have resolution problem on my fresh installed ubuntu 22.04.1

Tags: display-resolution

So i just installed ubuntu 22.04.1 from a bootable usb i made, but the resolution is only 800x600 and my computer uses 1920x1080 ,big difference, i tried many thing like verifying with xrandr,

Comment: Did try using the setting menu in the GUI of Ubuntu? Just click in the upper right corner of the desktop and then select *"Settings"*.
Why didn't you install the current Release of 22.04, which is 22.04.3?

Comment: Do you have a dedicated graphics card?

Comment: @ArchismanPanigrahi, i don't have dedicated graphics card....

Comment: should i remake the whole usb bootable process and install 22.04.3? @noisefloor

Comment: @andreeasimoc: no, not necessary. If you run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` you should receive the latest packages.